# 9k+ images in concequtive numbering. Want to sort every 200 into a folder named accordingly. BASH ubuntu

Tags: bash, loops, directory, filenames

Example of a filename near the end is = 09059.png

What i want to achieve is to split these files into folders. Each folder will contain 200 images. For example image 00001.png - 00200.png will be moved to a folder named [200].

The following is the pseudocode i sort of wriggled out for bash:

```
cnt=0

if $cnt<100
do

for i in *; do x=${f%%.*}; 

echo "Doing somthing to $x"; done;
fi

elsif $cnt=100 do 

mkdir "$cnt"
move all files scaned till the current cnt.

endif

reset
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'll settle for 100 files in a directory instead of 200, we can do it on one line:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].png' | sed 's/^\(.*\)\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\(.*\)$/mkdir -p \1\200 ; mv \1\2\3\4 \1\200\/\2\3\4/' | bash
```

Here's what it does:

- Find: Finds all files that are (5 digits).png, in the specified directory only.
- Sed: Does a find/replace on the output of Find.

  - Finds: a sequence of 3 digits, then 2 digits. Remember both groups of digits and all text before & after it on the line. The text before the digits will be the path, the text after it will be the extension.
  - Replace with two commands

    - mkdir -p (the path)(the first 3 digits)00
    - mv (the whole original path) (path)(the first 3 digits)00/(first 3 digits)(last 2 digits)(extension)
- And pipe the whole thing to Bash so it actually runs it.

If you want to test this, type the command, but replace `| bash` with `> file`. All the commands to be executed will be in the file. If you like, make it executable and run it there. Or delete the `| bash` and it will print to the screen.

My test: `touch 00000.png 00010.png 01010.png`

Result:

```
mkdir -p ./00000 ; mv ./00010.png ./00000/00010.png
mkdir -p ./00000 ; mv ./00000.png ./00000/00000.png
mkdir -p ./01000 ; mv ./01010.png ./01000/01010.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
source='/path1'
dest='/path2'
dir=200
echo mkdir "$dest/$dir"    # remove the echo if test succeeds

for file in "$source"/*
do
    if [[ -f "$file" ]]
    then
        echo mv "$file" "$dest/$dir"    # remove the echo if test succeeds
        ((count++))
        if (( ! ( count % 200 ) ))
        then
            ((dir += 200))    # dirs will be named 200, 400, 600, etc.
            echo mkdir "$dir"           # remove the echo if test succeeds
        fi
    fi
done
```